# TYPO3 - Extension_Builder extension for TYPO3 8.7.9?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I installed the current TYPO3 v8 LTS (8.7.9) and want to download and install the extension_builder extension on it, but it seems the latest version is for TYPO3 7.6. Is there a version of extension_builder that can be somehow manually downloaded that supports TYPO3 8.7.9? I remember there were versions beyond that specific one for TYPO3 7.6 available but needed to be manually downloaded. Where can i find those?

Answer (score 10):

It seems that all is missing is a release to the TER. So there are currently 2 ways to get the version for 8.7

- Use composer `composer require friendsoftypo3/extension-builder`
- Download it from https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/extension_builder/tree/8.7 and upload it as directory extension_builder to `typo3conf/ext`. You can't use the downloaded zip file in upload of EM.

Comment: I donwloaded the current extension builder version like you suggested and uploaded it. Then i added the entry to my PackageStates.php... BUT: In the BE, when i click on the Extension_Builder icon, i get an error: 'Could not analyse class: "EBT\ExtensionBuilder\Controller\BuilderModuleController" maybe not loaded or no autoloader? Class EBT\ExtensionBuilder\Controller\BuilderModuleController does not exist '

Comment: once you install this extension after clear all cache in Install Tool and remove typo3temp folder.

Comment: @mondblut : Not just clearing the cache but you need to regenerate the class autoload files. There is a function for that in the install tool. It is because you did not installed it but only uploaded. There is no automatic invokation from TYPO3 side.

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 v8 compatible version of `extension_builder` is now also available in the Extension Repository.

Answer (score -1):

If you are in the very beginning, you can try to install typo3 by Helmut Hummels pre configured composer installation. On this installation you have to add the version in composer file.

```
        "name": "friendsoftypo3/extension-builder",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/extension_builder.git",
            "reference": "4.........."
        },
```

Answer (score -2):

extension_builder is now compat with each major version of Typo3.

You can download the extension for Typo3 8.7 here : https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/extension_builder

TER is the Typo3 Extension Repository. You can search and download extensions for Typo3 CMS.
The link I provided redirect you to the page details of the extension you are looking for. On that page, your get the version details with typo3 version compatibility. Find yours, and download the extension.

OR if you are in composer mode, do it using composer and the command provided on the page : composer req friendsoftypo3/extension-builder

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: The link provide all the answers Oliver is looking for. I don't really get why I should explain what will be found on an extension download page other than links to the extension since the guy is looking for a specific extension version...
Anyway, I edited my answer